# Как обойти исключение SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

делаю дипломную, опыта нуль, поэтому строго не судите...
Представление Razor с привязанной моделью не принимает значения null из базы данных, а мне надо сделать так, чтобы в форме для редактирования данных пользователя(город проживания, место работы и т.д.) пользователю было видно какие поля он заполнил, а какие нет...
При регистрации помимо логина и пароля автоматически создаются другие таблицы со значениями null, их я и пытаюсь достать из базы данных через контроллер на страницу, но уже в контроллере выходит ошибка при попытке запроса:

```
var userProfile = await _context.UserProfile.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IdUser == id);
```

Контроллер:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyProfile()
        {
            int id=0;
            string statusPassword="";
            if (Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("IdUser") && Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("UserPassword"))
            {
                id = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["IdUser"]);
                statusPassword = Request.Cookies["UserPassword"];
            }

            if (statusPassword == "true" && id > 0)
            {
                var userProfile = await _context.UserProfile.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IdUser == id);
                if (userProfile == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                PortfolioContext db = new PortfolioContext();
                var img = db.ImgUser.Where(m => m.IdUser == id);
                var educationUser = await _context.Education.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IdUser == id);
                var userServices = await _context.UserServices.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IdUser == id);
                var userWorkplace = await _context.UserWorkplace.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IdUser == id);
                var userBiography = await _context.UserBiography.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IdUser == id);

                FullUser model = new FullUser();
                model.OneUser = userProfile;
                model.Image = img;
                model.EducationUser = educationUser;
                model.ServicesUser = userServices;
                model.WorkplaceUser = userWorkplace;
                model.BiographyUser = userBiography;
                return View(model);
                //return Redirect("/Home/Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect("/UserAuthorization/Index");
            }
        }
```

Модель код:

```
using System;

namespace SytePortfolio
{
    public partial class UserProfile
    {
        public int IdUser { get; set; }
        public string NameUser { get; set; }
        public string SurnameUser { get; set; }
        public string MiddlenameUser { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AgeUser { get; set; }
        public string AdressUser { get; set; }
        public string AmailUser { get; set; }
        public string PhoneUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

фрагмент из представления, где FullUser это класс моделей:

```
@model SytePortfolio.FullUser

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Мой профиль";
}

<h1>Мой профиль</h1>

<div>
    <a asp-controller="UserPortfolio" asp-action="Create" >Добавить портфолио</a> |
    <a asp-controller="BlogUsers" asp-action="Create">Добавить блог</a> |
    <a asp-controller="UserPortfolio" asp-action="MyPortfolios">Мои портфолио</a> |
    <a asp-controller="BlogUsers" asp-action="MyBlogs">Мои блоги</a>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div>
        @foreach (var img in @Model.Image)
        {
            <img style='width:45%;' src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(img.DataImg))" />
        }
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>@if (Model.BiographyUser.StatusUser != null)@Model.BiographyUser.StatusUser;</p>
        <p>@if (Model.BiographyUser.NameHistoryBiography != null)@Model.BiographyUser.NameHistoryBiography;</p>
        <p>@if (Model.BiographyUser.UserHistory != null)@Model.BiographyUser.UserHistory;</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ваша ошибка **Sql**NullValueException намекает на то что проблема не в Razor'e а в базе, посмотрите существует ли пользователь в базе данных с тем id который в передаете в базу.

Comment: Явно указывал, проблема именно в том, что все значения кроме id пустые т.е. null. Это можно решить, если указывать в базе данных некоторые значения по умолчанию, но, что делать с остальными null, когда дело доходит до страницы Razor

Comment: а вы пробовали заполнить руками данные в базе и попробовать их получить в коде?

Comment: Да, тогда их можно получить в контроллере вместе с другими данными в том числе null, но страница Razor не принимает значения null

Comment: например уже в условии <p>@if (Model.BiographyUser.StatusUser != null) ...выдает ошибку...

Comment: *_context.Education.FirstOrDefaultAsync выдает исключение* - `try { } catch { }` вам поможет

Answer (score 0):

Добавил значение DEFAULT в один столбец для каждой таблицы БД, так как запрос _context.Education.FirstOrDefaultAsync выдает исключение, если объект совсем пустой...